# Standardize 2D/3D Vector / Coordinate Class

Tags: c++, stl, standards

**Question**
This is something that's bugging me for some time now, but I couldn't find a definitive answer for it:

- Is anyone aware of a proposal to introduce a standard 2D and/or 3D Vector (a struct with x,y and z members) to the STL?
- If not, is there a realistic way to get such a class into the next version of the standard - short of writing a complete and perfectly written proposal myself?
- And, are there any good reasons (aside from no one having the time) why this hasn't already been done?

I'm definitely willing to contribute, but I believe I lack the experience to produce something of high enough quality to get accepted (I'm not a professional programmer).

**Reasoning / Background**
By now I've seen dozens of libraries and frameworks (be it for graphics, physics, math, navigation, sensor fusion ...) which all basically implement their own version of

```
struct Vector2d {
    double x,y;
    //...
};
/* ...
 * operator overloads
 */
```

and/or its 3D equivalent - not to mention all the occasions, where I implemented one myself before I took the time to do a proper, reusable version.
Obviously, this is not something difficult and I'm not worrying about suboptimal implementations, but every time, I want to combine two libraries or reuse code from a different project, I have to take care of converting one version into the other (either by casting or - if possible - text replacement).

Now that the committee strives to significantly extend the standard library for c++17 (especially with a 2D graphics framework), I really would like to have a common 2D vector baked into all interfaces from the start, so I can just write e.g.:

```
drawLine(transformCoordinates(trackedObject1.estimatePos(),params), 
         transformCoordinates(trackedObject2.estimatePos(),params));
```

rather than

```
MyOwnVec2D t1{trackedObject1.estimatePosX(), trackedObject1.estPosY()};
MyOwnVec2D t2{trackedObject2.estimatePosX(), trackedObject2.estPosY()};

t1 = transformCoordinates(t1,params);
t2 = transformCoordinates(t2,params);

drawLine(t1.x,t1.y,t2.x,t2.y);
```

The example might be a little exaggerated, but I think it shows my point.

I'm aware of `std::valarray`, which already goes in the right direction, as it allows standard operations like addition and multiplication, but it carries far too much weight if all you need are two or three coordinates. I think a valarray, with fixed size and no dynamic memory allocation (e.g. based on `std::array`) would be an acceptable solution, especially as it would come with a trivial iterator implementation, but I personally would prefer a class with x, y (and z) members.

*Remark*: I'm sorry if this topic has already been discussed (and I would be surprised if it hasn't), but every time I'm searching for 2d vectors I get results talking about something like `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` or how to implement a certain transformation, but nothing on the topic of standardization.

Comment: *is there a realistic way to get such a class into the next version of the standard - short of writing a complete and perfectly written proposal myself?* - convincing someone else to do that. That's how C++ evolves.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: Any hints on how to do this or where to ask for help with writing the proposal (if you are not working in a SW company)?

Comment: I'd start with reading existing proposals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> are there any good reasons (aside from no one having the time) why this hasn't already been done?

There's essentially no reason to.

Forming a type that contains two or three elements is utterly trivial, and all the operations can be trivially defined too. Furthermore, the C++ standard library is not intended to be a general-purpose mathematical toolsuite: it makes sense to use specialised third-party libraries for that if you are serious about mathematical types and constructs beyond the functions and operators that you can throw together in half an hour.

And we do not standardise things that do not need to be standardised.

If C++ were to gain some kind of standardised 3D graphics API then I can see this changing but not until then. And hopefully C++ will never gain any kind of standardised 3D graphics API, because that is not what it is for.

However, if you feel strongly about it, you can start a conversation on [std-discussion](https://isocpp.org/forums/iso-c-standard-discussion#!forum/std-discussion) where all the experts (and some assuredly non-experts) live; sometimes such conversations lead to the formation of proposals, and it needn't necessarily be you who ends up writing it.

Comment: If C++ were to gain some kind of standardised 3d graphics API, then surely it will be generalized to work with your coordinate type of choice. C++ likes to pay only for what you need, not "taxes" at every API boundary toll booth.

Comment: @sehe: Maybe I'm completely missing your point, but how? One implementation uses plain data members, another setter and getter methods. One might name the coordinates x, y, z, the other x1,x2,x3 and the third might require array style access.

Comment: @MikeMB See [**Boost Geometry** Design Rationale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/design.html), and e.g. the whole **[Boost Propertymap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/property_map/doc/property_map.html)** library.. Generalizing access is a key tool in versatile C++ API design

Comment: @Lightness Thanks for the explanation and the suggestion on how to go forward. My opinion is that just because something is easy to implement doesn't mean there is no value in having a standardized version of it, which can be used by everyone. As stated in the question, vectors are used in a lot of different applications and I think a standardized vector could potentially ease the composition of functionalities from different libraries. Btw. I just realized, that the current proposal for 2D Graphics (N4073) has a point class (I only looked at an old version before)

Comment: @sehe: While I think thats a great mechanism I have my doubts whether this will actually be standardized and used inside the standard c++ library in the foreseeable future - especially, if all you want is to pass 2-3 doubles as parameters. Or do you have any other information in that direction?

Comment: @MikeMB: _"My opinion is that just because something is easy to implement doesn't mean there is no value in having a standardized version of it, which can be used by everyone."_ Right, and that's not what I said, either. There is no value in having a standardized version for many reasons, _and_ because it's easy to implement there is no overriding need to avoid the code duplication. **We add things to the standard _because we need them_, not because we don't need to avoid them.**

Comment: @MikeMB Precisely. I wasn't arguing that this is likely to be standardized. I was just refuting your claim that it couldn't be usefully done. (Re. _"if all you want is to pass 2-3 doubles as parameters"_ - the adaptor/accessor layer would hide this; The standard API should not commit such interface sins though: `makeRect({1,13},{3,14})` is almost as brief as `makeRect(1,13,3,14)` and a lot more descriptive. That's basically the same problem with algorithms taking iterators instead of ranges, though. We learned from that)

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else has an interest in it, I wanted to point out that the July 2014 version of [*"A Proposal to Add 2D Graphics Rendering and Display to C++"*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4073.pdf) includes a 2D point class / struct (my question was based on the initial draft from January 2014). So maybe there will be at least a simple standard 2D-Vector in c++1z.